# String Manipulation in UNIX

Tags: string, bash, unix

I have a script that after running, will shows:

```
The square 1 with the name Square with area 10 is created
The square 2 with the name Box with area 20 is created
The circle with the name Spinny with area 22 is not created
The rectangle with the name Tri with area 30 is created.
```

How can I retrieve all the numbers between area and is created and store it into an array?

stored array will be:

```
10
20
30
```

The tricky part is that, I cannot just find the first number, as square (1) will be read,
I cannot also do take the number between "area" and "is" as it might take in shapes that are not created.
any idea how to do this?

Comment: Does the last line really end with a period, whereas all the other lines don't?

Comment: Not really.. haha, ignore the period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ cat testfile
The square 1 with the name Square with area 10 is created
The square 2 with the name Box with area 20 is created
The circle with the name Spinny with area 22 is not created
The rectangle with the name Tri with area 30 is created.
$ grep -Eo 'area [0-9]+ is created' testfile | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
10
20
30
```

**NOTE** POSIX grep doesn't support `-o`, but this should work on BSD and GNU greps.

Comment: @kojiro, Thank you for comment. I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. the -o is the key that I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

### awk

```
awk '/area [[:digit:]]+ is created/{ print $(NF-2); }'
```

Prints the third-to-last field on matching lines.

```
array=( $(awk '/area [[:digit:]]+ is created/{ print $(NF-2); }' <<< "$input") )
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
10
20
30
```

### pure bash

```
array=()
while read -a line; do
  if [[ "${line[@]: -2:1}" = is && "${line[@]: -1}" = created ]]; then
    array+=( "${line[@]: -3:1}" )
  fi
done <<< "$input"
printf '%s, ' "${array[@]}" # Will output 10, 20 if there's a period on the last line...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array=( $(sed -n 's/.*with area \([0-9][0-9]*\) is created.*/\1/p' data) )
```

The `array=( ... )` notation is an array assignment in `bash`.  The `$(...)` is command substitution.  The `sed` command does not print by default, but when a line matches 'with area XX is created' (where XX is a number of one or more digits), then the line is replaced with the value of XX and printed.

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu grep (Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions)

```
grep -Po '(?<=area )[0-9]* (?=is created)' file
```

Using sed

```
sed -n 's/.* area \([0-9]*\) is created.*/\1/p' file
```